# Error using SharedElementTransition with recyclerView

Tags: android, animation

I've a recyclerView and an ImageView in it which im getting from Firebase Database. I'm trying to pass the Image of the recyclerView to a new activity using SharedElementTransition

My transition code in my adatper Class is given below:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,ProductPage.class);
                intent.putExtra("Node", node.getText().toString());
                ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity),
                        image, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(image));
                context.startActivity(intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());


            }
        });
```

Error is given below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window android.app.Activity.getWindow()' on a null object reference
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iinsted of **Activity** in **ActivityOptionsCompat** ,use **ActvityName.this** .

```
ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity)context,
                    image, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(image));
```

or

try to make click listener for recycleview item inside your activity ,and use ActivityName.this.

```
ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ActivityName.this,
                        image, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(image));
```

Comment: I'm using it in an adapter class

Comment: ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity)context,
                    image, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(image));

Try thiscode.

Comment: I have already tried this......it says android.app.application cannot be cast to android.app.activity

Comment: The try to pass Activity.this inside adapter contructor or make click listener for recycleview item inside your activity ,and use ActivityName.this.check this link:https://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-4-recyclerview/

Comment: I've solved the above problem, however now when the activity opens....there is no image?
Is this because I'm loading the image using picasso from firebase database?

Comment: No,but check your onError method of picaaso or check your code with above link which is in my comment.

Comment: In first activity the image opens fine....in second activity after the transition, there is no image....

Comment: Have you checked **onAnimalItemClick** method of my suggestion link?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using it in an adapter. You have to case the context to the activity and then use it.

```
ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity)getContext(),
                    image, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(image));
```

Comment: I cannot directly user getContext method in an adapter class

Comment: Get the context from one of the views in the viewholder.